# how to send array from controller to layout header in yii?

Tags: layout, view, yii, controller

I might be wrong.But is it possible to send array from controller to **layout ->header.php** in YII as controller  send array data to view file?

Answer (score 2):

```
public $variable;

public function actionView(){
    $model = blabla::model()->findbypk($id);
    $this->variable = $model->name;
    $this->render('view', array('model'=>$model));
}

and then, you can use $this->variable in your layout
```

Comment: May i ask to describe it more? The layout is whole page of the website and a view is a part of it, So how to use that array in out of that view part, for Example in Sidebar or in the header or footer?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you. Needed to pass to my layout a variable defining which items would be rendered in a menu.

In my case I decided to create a Widget.

I imported in the configuration file:

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.widgets.Menu'
)
```

the Menu class:

```
class Menu extends CWidget{

            public function init(){}

            public function run(){

                $rs = Yii::db()->menus->find(array('profile' => Yii::app()->user->profile));

                $this->render('menu', array(
                    'menus' => $rs['menus']
                ));
            }

        }
```

and the menu view:

```
foreach($menus as $key=>$menu): ?>

    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $menu['url']; ?>"><?php echo $menu['name']; ?></a>
    </li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In the layout I imported the widget:

```
<ul class="menus">
       $this->widget('application.widgets.Menu');
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot pass a variable from controller to layout. It is "by design" as mentioned to by one of the yii staff. You can however, declare a variable in your controller class and call that variable in your layout by

```
your html code here ...

   <h1> <?php echo $this->variableName; ?> </h1>
```

Note: the variable or the property in your controller class is static so there's not much of a flexibility in this approach.